# Kernel Module Loading Error: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout

Tags: linux-device-driver

Have anyone encountered this problem while loading a kernel module with:
`insmod foo.ko`

***Kernel Module Loading Error: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout***

I compiled the kernel module on a my **local VM** and load it on the **remote VM** of customer. You might be wondering why didn't I compile and run the kernel module on the same **remote VM** to avoid headache of kernel version incompatibility. Problem is, I'm not allowed to reveal the source code and compile on the **remote VM** since the code is not my own property. I can only ship to the the **remote VM** the pre-build kernel module.

Big headache is that the kernel version of **remote VM** must match the kernel version of **local VM**, even the patch number needs to be matched. This is very inconvenient, since I need to prepare the kernel version of my **local VM** to match kernel version of **remote VM**. Every time **remote VM** updates its kernel version to whatever version, I need to also upgrade my **local VM** to match the customer's version accordingly and build the customer the kernel module again...

Could it be possible to build a kernel module that will be compatible with all kernel version release? Thank you a lot for reading this far :).

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125624/unable-to-load-module-disagrees-about-version-of-symbol-module-layout